# Wrong result in Wolfram Alpha on graph

Tags: graphing-functions, wolfram-alpha, python

I'm learning to code in Python, so I tried to find roots and draw a graph of a function
$-(16x^2-24x+5)e^{-x}$  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnnY8.png)

Result i got in Python using the mat.plotlib library is this 
[image]

The problem is that Wolfram alpha is giving me the same graph, but it's incorrect. 
If you use x=1 in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnnY8.png), y =1.104, not 0 as Wolfram alpha or Python are showing. I'm confused why Wolfram and even Python are plotting wrong graphs?

Answer (score 6):

At the scale of your graph you can't tell $y=0$ from $y=1.104$.  The scale comes from starting the plot around $x=-5$ where the function value is almost $-80000.$  If we plot it in [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20-%2816x%5E2-24x%2B5%29e%5E%28-x%29%20from%200%20to%202) with a range of $0$ to $2$ we can see that at $x=1$ the value is around $1$
[image]

Comment: Ohhh, God, where was my mind. Thanks You very much. I got total blockade.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct and the graphs are correct too. What you see as zero is  not really zero.

Your confusion is about the scale of the curves.

If you check the scale you see that it changes from $-10000$ to zero in a tiny space so the distnace between zero and $1.104$ is so small that you see it as zero.

If you cahnge your widow to $[-2,2]\times [-2,2]$ then you see the difference.

Comment: Thank You very much Mohammed.